# Set current date and time as release APK name in GitHub workflows

Tags: flutter, github, github-actions, github-api, cicd

I have a GitHub workflow for releasing nightly snapshots of the repository. This is how the workflow file looks right now:

```
# Define workflow name
name: main

# This workflow is triggered on pushes to the repository.
on:
  push:
    branches:
    - main
        
jobs:
  build:
    # This job will run on windows virtual machine
    runs-on: windows-latest

    steps:
    # Setup Java environment in order to build the Android app.
    - uses: actions/checkout@v1
    - uses: actions/setup-java@v1
      with:
        java-version: '12.x'

    # Setup the flutter environment.
    - uses: subosito/flutter-action@v1
      with:
        channel: 'stable' # 'dev', 'alpha', default to: 'stable'
        flutter-version: '3.3.7' # version of flutter
    
    # Get flutter dependencies.
    - run: flutter clean
    - run: flutter pub get
    
    # Build apk.
    - run: flutter build apk --release
    
    # Upload generated apk to the artifacts.
    - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
      with:
        name: app-release # want to set current date time over here
        path: build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-release.apk
```

I want current datetime as release apk name. However, I couldn't find any documentation on it. How should I do it?

Answer (score 1):

You can specify versionName and versionCode in the `android/local.properties`

```
flutter.versionName=YOUR-DATE-HERE
flutter.versionCode=1
```

**UPDATE**

You can specify the exact file name of generated `apk` file by modifying `build.gradle` file

```
    buildTypes {
        applicationVariants.all{
            variant ->
                variant.outputs.each{
                    // on below line we are setting a name to our apk
                    output->
                        def formattedDate = new Date().format('yyyy-MM-dd-HH-mm-ss')
                        output.outputFileName = formattedDate
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: want to set the current date as release APK name, not the version name.

Comment: Do you mean apk file name or what exactly do you mean under apk name?

Comment: apk file name in the workflow.

Comment: Modify build.gradle file as described in my updated answer

Comment: then anything changes in the workflow file?

Comment: It just rename you apk file and will not affect on anything else

Comment: it's not working - the name is still app-release.apk